# Unable to get the App Install error

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, sharepoint-addin, remote-event-receiver

I have created a provider-hosted add-in which contain Remote event receiver. but when I try to add the add-in inside my site collection (modern communication site), I got one installation error, as follow:-
[image]

but if I click on the error I will be redirected to an empty page, so I am unable to understand what is causing the app to fail to install.
any advice, how I can get the install error details?